# Target applet or JVM process exited abruptly

Tags: java, applet, jvm

I'm getting message `Target applet or JVM process exited abruptly` sometimes and its not coming continuously so I can't trace the log before Java Console closes. I tried to increase heap size using

`<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m">`  ,

`<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx300m">` ,

`<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx512m">`

but its not working. Same question already asked. I also tried to load Applet in separate JVM using

`<PARAM name="separate_jvm" value="true">`

http://www.techques.com/question/1-11284843/uncaught-exception:-Target-applet-or-JVM-process-exited-abruptly---from-a-firefox-extension

[uncaught exception: Target applet or JVM process exited abruptly - from a firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284843/uncaught-exception-target-applet-or-jvm-process-exited-abruptly-from-a-firefo)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676722/target-jvm-seems-to-have-already-exited

Comment: There is not enough here to answer the question, without console output or something.  Try **removing** VM arguments one-by-one until it does run, and then add them back one-by-one until it doesn't, and you'll have your culprit.

Comment: OS and JRE vendor+version please... also check system logs as the JVM process could have been killed (might be bug in the plugin container). And last - isn't this error happening on page unload?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your client to run the applet as fully trusted, there's several things you can do:

1. Install a [default exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)), and have it send the exception information to you.
2. Call [System.setOut()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) and [System.setErr()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr(java.io.PrintStream)) and send the results to you.
3. [Install shutdown hooks and a security manager to get told when the JVM is shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714828/how-to-generate-thread-dumps-when-jvm-terminates-automatically/10715173#10715173)

Otherwise you might try:

1. Creating a non-daemon thread and have it sleep forever, to try to prevent the applet from closing by having at least one thread active. (Having hardly any experience with applets, I'm not sure if this would work).
2. Use the [Java logging system](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) and have the information be sent to you, in the hopes that the problem that causes the crash logs something right before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than run the app directly out of Windows, open a command line editor session.  When the program crashes, the window will not go away, allowing you to read the "entrails" at your leisure.

Comment: We can't tell client to do so..... I need full proof solution as I mentioned. Its not coming on regular basis.