# Internet Explorer 11 Java 1.7 Applet crash "Target jvm seems to have already exited"

Tags: java, ajax, applet, jvm, internet-explorer-11

I am developing an application that use an applet for signing documents.
Everything works fine, but if you try to sign two times in a row the applet fails and shows this error:

**"Target jvm seems to have already exited"**

The funny thing is that this problem only occurs in Internet Explorer 11 in Firefox is working properly. But the corporative browser is IE11, so there is no option to use another.

I'm using Java 1.7.0_51-b13 compilation.

Thanks in advance, greetings.

> Edit

A curious thing is that sometimes this problem does not occur when I use an ajax modal dialog. From what I could see in the Java console is as if the virtual machine is rebooted in the moment I finish of using the modal dialog, and from that reset would work as expected, allowing signing the time it takes.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788941/target-applet-or-jvm-process-exited-abruptly

Comment: None of the solutions worked.
The exception is captured correctly, and I check the error, which is described in the question.
On the other hand, I should not modify the applet, I should only modify the javascript that inizialize the applet, or browser settings.
I edit response to include new information that may be important.